# What is the different between 127.0.0.1 and ::1

Tags: sockets, networking, localhost

Originally, there is one third library used in my legacy codes, and one IP address configuration for it. Its default value is `localhost`. For `IPV4`, we know, the value of `localhost` is `127.0.0.1`.

However, I find this value changed to `::1`. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address), `::1` represents the `localhost` for `IPV6` and whole address is `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`.

Here are my questions:

- Is there any different between `127.0.0.1` and `::1`? If `::1` is used, any impact on my program?
- For the `localhost` configuration. Why `127.0.0.1` is used sometime, while `::1` is used sometime? Does it depend on the OS?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is an IPv4 address, `::1` is an IPv6 address

Answer (score 2):

`127.0.0.1` is an [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) address while `::1` is the equivalent [IPv6](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/IPv6) address.

There is no other difference beside the IP protocol version between the two. Semantically, they behave the same, *as long as your stack* supports both protocols.